# Getting an error while the project running on android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying run my project on android. But I get an error like that.

```js
C:\Users\Alperen\Desktop\AwesomeProject>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Alperen\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Alperen\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at C:\Users\Alperen\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Alperen\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

I don't understand. What should I do ?

Comment: You need to set the JAVA_HOME like this in Environment Variables - JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"

Comment: Yes you have to download and install a recent version [Java SE Development Kit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and set the JAVA_HOME Environment Variable. You can find a pretty good tutorial [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)